# CDI + JPA repository

Tags: java, jpa, cdi, java-ee-7

I'm trying a simple way to inject my EntityManager inside a repository. Would I have side effects?

Managed Bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Teste implements Serializable {

@Inject
Repository repo;

}
```

Repository

```
@RequestScoped
public class Repository {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="Test")
    EntityManager em;

}
```

Is it safe to use this approach? I'm worried about multiple requests to this web app.

Comment: Depends a little bit.  What container and version?

Comment: The `@PersistenceContext` injection itself makes sense.  Is the specific issue that you're injecting a request-scoped Repository into your session-scoped Teste class with a longer lifespan?   I *think* this is OK because CDI will inject a request-scoped proxy that will get you a fresh Repository on each request even though Teste is session-scoped.

Comment: @JohnAment, I'm using Wildfly 8.2, Java 8.

Comment: @wrschneider, the repository has a request scope to keep the rule "one session per request". I think is a good pratice.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe to use this approach? I'm worried about multiple requests
>   to this web app.

For me it is a perfectly valid approach. So I'm a little bit curious why @JohnAment said:

> It depends a little bit. What container and version?.

AFAIK it will work regardless of the container. Can somebody correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: I suppose it would only matter if the container's implementation of the spec was wrong, but you'd probably have bigger problems in that case.